# Laravel Export to Excel

Tags: php, laravel, export

I want to be able to export a table to excel.

I am using Maatwebsite and been trying to use the From View method. However its giving me following error..

**Undefined variable: trip (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\basicwebsite\resources\views\share.blade.php)**

**TripsExport.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Trip;
use App\Events;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class TripsExport implements FromView
{
    public function  view() : View
    {
      return view('share', [
        'events' => Events::all(),
      ]);
    }
}
```

**share.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<a href="{{route('export', 'xlsx')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Export Itinerary</a>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Event Name</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>Emd Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($trip->events as $event)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $event->event_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $event->start_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ $event->end_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ $event->time }}</td>
            <td>{{ $event->address }}</td>
            <td>{{ $event->notes }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

@endsection
```

**TripController.php**

```
public function export($type = 'xls')
    {
      return Excel::download(new TripsExport, 'itinerary.' . $type);
    }

public function share($id)
    {
      //$events = Events::all();
      $trip = Trip::findOrFail($id);
      $trips = Trip::all();
      $events = Events::get();

      return view ('share')->with([
        'events'           => $events,
        'trip'             => $trip
      ]);
    }
```

**routes**

```
Route::get('export/{type?}', 'TripController@export')->name('export');
Route::get('/share/{id}', 'TripController@share')->name('trips.share');
```

The data is showing correctly in the view I just want to export this to excel.

Once the Export button is clicked that i where I get the error...

[image]

Comment: in your share method, I think it should be **'trip'=>$trips** with an s because you want the collection not a single item,

Comment: where are you using destination on your share.blade.php ? I don't see it on the post.

Comment: sorry I actually get the error `Property [events] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\basicwebsite\resources\views\share.blade.php)`

Comment: remove **->events** from the $trip variable

Comment: Please show the code of **TripsExport** class you have used in the **export** function.

Comment: Its in the first section of code above